# React native project api data is fetched successfully but image is not at all loading

Tags: react-native

In my react native project   api data is fetched successfully but image is not at all loading in some mobile device especially in 1PLUS 7t .Please help me out how to resolve this issue?
API is working successfully in some mobile device but not in some other mobile device.Basically image loading issue.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in the application tag of your manifest file:

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```